# VIM get E488: Trailing characters error

Tags: vim

I'd like to implement a function that can get VirtualEnv name from a file named .env and then execute CondaChangeEnv VirtualEnvName.

```
function! SetVirtualEnv()
    let cmd = "sed -n '1,1p' ". $PWD . "/.env"
    let result = 'CondaChangeEnv ' . system(cmd)
    if !v:shell_error
        exe result
    endif
endfunction
autocmd FileType python call SetVirtualEnv()
```

But, it seems like something is wrong

```
E488: Trailing characters: CondaChangeEnv G
```

G is the content of .env and generated by `echo -n 'G' >> .env`

So, anybody can help me? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [vim-conda](https://github.com/cjrh/vim-conda) is a vim bundle

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source codes of your plugin:

```
command! CondaChangeEnv call s:CondaChangeEnv()
```

The `CondaChangeEnv` command expects no parameter, but you passed a `G` to it. That's the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. and any solution can help me to do like this, open vim and then type ` :CondaChangeEnv G ` in Command line mode？